# Resize image to fill div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to resize an image to fill its container div without skewing the image. It uses css to fill by height and if the image is not wide enough to fill the div then the function uses width to fill the div and sets height to auto. The problem is the code only works with window.load, so if the user is paying attention they can see the image load, then after a second it changes. So how would I change the function to work with document.ready?

```
function imageResize() {
  $(".square").each(function(){
    if($("img",this).width() < $(this).width()){
        $("img",this).css("height", "auto");
        $("img",this).css("width", "100%");
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: The problem with using document.ready with the current function is if the image is to big, the document is "ready" before the image has loaded. So my guess to fixing this is getting the length and width of the actual image from the file, before the image has to load on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function inside the ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  imageResize();
});
```

If you want to use it on resize the call the function on resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  imageResize();
});
```

Use your code inside the load handler to get the image dimension which works fine:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  imageResize();
});
```

Comment: I know to put it in the document.ready function, but the problem is, the image isn't loaded when the document is ready, so that doesn't work. My guess I would have to do something with getting the actual image dimensions.

Comment: This usually works, but if the file is big then there is still a delay, so the user can see the image load with 100% height and then it changes about a second later.

Comment: to solve that problem first hide them with css and show them within load function and use imageResize() ....